# Как сделать выборку строк с MAX значением столбца, с применённым DISTINCT'ом к другому столбцу в SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы: wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4 и wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код у меня сейчас такой:

```
SELECT wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.*,                             
       wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4.*                             
FROM wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access, wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4 
WHERE wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4.lessonNum = wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.lessonNum 
AND wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.userId= '". (int)$user_ID."' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Застрял на том, что надо сделать выборку DISTINCT lessonNum из таблицы wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access, но чтобы при этом выбиралась строка с максимальным статусом для выбранного номера урока. 
То есть должно получиться:

```
lessonNum | status
-------------------
     1    |    3
     2    |    0
     3    |    0
     4    |    3
     5    |    2
     6    |    3
```

Проблема в том, что сейчас в выдачу попадают строки с одинаковыми lessonNum и разными статусами:

```
lessonNum | status
-------------------
     1    |    1
     1    |    3
     2    |    0
     3    |    0
     4    |    1
     4    |    3
     5    |    2
     6    |    3
```

Я уже перепробовал всё, что было [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql).
Когда подставляю в код вариант, который там является решением, то у меня выбираются строки только с максимальным статусом в принципе, т.е. только те, где он принимает значение 3

Вот этот код, адаптированный под мой вариант:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access as t1
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT lessonNum, MAX(status) as MaxStatus
        FROM wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access
        GROUP BY lessonNum) as t2 
    ON t1.lessonNum = t2.lessonNum
    AND t1.status = t2.MaxStatus
WHERE userId = 553
```

Но тут ещё один момент: так как в mysql/php я чайник, то совершенно не понимаю, как этот адаптированный вариант ещё и совместить со второй таблицей, то есть сджойнить их? Очень сильно путаюсь в этих многоярусных конструкциях.

Comment: Какое поле связывает первую и вторую таблицу? Какую таблицу хотите получить в результате джоинов?

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko таблицы связаны через поле lessonNum. В итоге нужна таблица, в которой будут практически все столбцы из обеих таблиц.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  t3.*
FROM
  wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access AS t1
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      t2_fake.lessonNum,
      MAX(t2_fake.status) AS maxStatus
    FROM
      wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access AS t2_fake
    WHERE
      t2_fake.userId = 553
    GROUP BY t2_fake.lessonNum
  ) AS t2 ON t2.lessonNum = t1.lessonNum AND t2.maxStatus = t1.status
  LEFT JOIN wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4 AS t3 ON t3.lessonNum = t1.lessonNum
WHERE
  t1.userId = 553
```

Comment: Вы гений! спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: Чудесно) Только сделайте поле `lessonNum` в `wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4` уникальным, а то могут строчки дублироваться

Comment: Если честно, страшно что-то ковырять уже. Всё работает на честном слове)) когда дорасту, чтобы нанять к себе в штат программиста за мной всё в нормальный вид приводить, надо будет следить, чтобы он из окна не выбросился)